# Which is best Immutable JS data structure for JSON Object types in redux.?

Tags: json, reactjs, data-structures, redux, immutable.js

I am using `spread operators` in **redux** to arrange data like `JSON Object` format as given below:

**Filename:** `redux.js`

```
export default function appData(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_LAYERS':
    return {
      ...state, appElements: action.data.appElements
    }

    case 'ADD_ITEMS':
    return {
        ...state,appElements:{ ...state.appElements,
        layers: { ...state.appElements.layers,
          ['layer_1']:{ ...state.appElements.layers.layer_1,
            ['items']:{ ...state.appElements.layers.layer_1.items,
              [action.objData.item_id]:{
                "width":action.objData.width,
                "x":action.objData.x
              },
            }
          },
        }
      }
    }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Where `case 'ADD_LAYERS':` of `action.data.appElements` will add:(data from external json file stored as object key value pairs)

```
layers: {
  layer_1: {
    background: {
      width: '100px',
      height: '100px',
      bgColor: '#aaaaaa',
      bgImage: 'http:bgimage1.png'
    },
    items: {
    }
  },
  layer_2: {
    background: {
      width: '200px',
      height: '200px',
      bgColor: '#bbbbbb',
      bgImage: 'http:bgimage2.png'
    },
    items: {
    }
  },
  layer_3: {
    background: {
      width: '300px',
      height: '300px',
      bgColor: '#cccccc',
      bgImage: 'http:bgimage3.png'
    },
    items: {
    }
  }
}
```

Where `case 'ADD_ITEMS':` will add `layer_1` items:

```
yrgroih9: {
  width: '100px',
  x: '200px'
}
```

**Final redux store will look like as given below:**

```
{
  appElements: {
    layers: {
      layer_1: {
        background: {
          width: '100px',
          height: '100px',
          bgColor: '#aaaaaa',
          bgImage: 'http:bgimage1.png'
        },
        items: {
          yrgroih9: {
            width: '100px',
            x: '200px'
          },
          qhy0dukj: {
            width: '100px',
            x: '200px'
          },
          '7lw2nvma': {
            width: '100px',
            x: '200px'
          }
        }
      },
      layer_2: {
        background: {
          width: '200px',
          height: '200px',
          bgColor: '#bbbbbb',
          bgImage: 'http:bgimage2.png'
        },
        items: {
          sdfsdsvod: {
            width: '555px',
            x: '111px'
          },
          sdfcasadf: {
            width: '333px',
            x: '222px'
          },
          'xcvxcver': {
            width: '555px',
            x: '444px'
          }
        }
      },
      layer_3: {
        background: {
          width: '300px',
          height: '300px',
          bgColor: '#cccccc',
          bgImage: 'http:bgimage3.png'
        },
        items: {
          dfsgdfgfg: {
            width: '555px',
            x: '111px'
          },
          sfgdyrsdf: {
            width: '333px',
            x: '222px'
          },
          'dsfdhsfdf': {
            width: '777px',
            x: '444px'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to move from `redux spread operators` to [Immutable Js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) for better functionalities like `create`,`read`,`update` and `delete` in **redux store data**.

Which will be the best [Immutable Js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) data structure **(List, Stack, Map, OrderedMap, Set, OrderedSet and Record)** suits for the above given store manipulations
in both structure and performance..?

Answer (score 0):

For your current state object the most natural data structure is `Map` unless you need a specific order for the items, in that case, go with `OrderedMap`